# JS function - function that reloads an iframe doesn't refresh when called from another function

Tags: javascript, button, iframe, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to Javascript and have encountered something strange with refreshing iframes.  I have a function that reloads the iframe's content:

```
function refreshIframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

I have a Bootstrap button that calls the function, and it does exactly what I want - fetches the most updated version of the iframe:

```
<button id="saveButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="refreshIframe();">Refresh</button>
```

But when I call the function from another function, it doesn't get the most up-to-date version of the iframe like the button does:

```
function startUpdate(d) {
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    document.getElementById("comment").value = '';
    updateFunction(comment);
    refreshIframe();
}
```

I basically have some text input that I submit, which through the updateFunction(comment); updates the content of the iframe. But just calling refreshIframe at the end doesn't seem to yield the same result as calling it from 'onclick'.

Is looked into caching but didn't seem to be it.

Thanks

Comment: Is your function being called when you debug? (the refreshIframe)

Comment: Yes, in both instances the function is called with the same src to the iframe.